# Unable to Return value from text file

Tags: javascript

I am Unable to Return value from text file and am getting an error when i try to return notepad value,

**Error**: Uncaught ReferenceError: txtData is not defined

```
   function readTextFile(file)
{
    //let txtData='';
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "textFiles/"+file, true);
    rawFile.onload = function (){

        if(this.status===200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
           let txtData= String(this.responseText);
        }
        else{

            let txtData='';
        }
    }

    rawFile.send();
    return txtData;
}

var taskStatus=readTextFile("file1.txt")
    if(taskStatus==='complete')
    {
          console.log('completed..')
    }
    else{
        console.log('Not completed..')  
    }
```

Comment: Notepad? Also, why is this tagged node.js if you're showing clientside code with XHR?

Comment: Using `let` confines the variable to that block. Uncomment the first declaration, remove `let` from the else block and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried removing let from if and else, but getting the same error

Comment: uncomment let txtData also

Comment: You can't return txtData because it gets set in the asynchronous onload handler for the XHR. The handler will (probably) not have completed by the time you run `return txtData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the variable with `let txtData='';`, its scope is limited to the block in which it is declared - such are the semantics of the `let` keyword. Therefore, the variable is not available outside of the `else {...}` block.

There's a deeper problem here, however. You are assigning a value to `txtData` in an *asynchronous* event handler; as a result, you can't return this value from the `readTextFile` function without either also making it asynchronous, or waiting for the handler to run (which would make it synchronous instead). I would encourage you to read [the MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) on asynchronous programming in JS.

Comment: Is there any way we can return read data from text file outside the function?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that the onload handler (the function where `txtData` is set) runs asynchronously with the main flow of the method. Think about it like this: you're saying "hey, when the XHR finishes loading, do this thing". Your function doesn't wait for the XHR to load - it just tells it what to do *when, at some point in the future, it loads*. Your function returns as soon as this command is issued, not when the onload handler actually runs, and so `txtData` is still undefined when you return.

Long story short: No. Either pass a callback argument, or return a promise.